# The Group expression for the grouping ‘Origin2’ contains an error: Argument 'Length' must be greater or equal to zero. (rsRuntimeErrorInExpression)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am getting this error every time this report is rendered. I looked at the group expression for this group and it looks like this:

```
=Trim(Left(Fields!ILS_LS_USER_10.Value,InStr(Fields!ILS_LS_USER_10.Value,"->")-2))
```

The field ILS_LS_USER_10.Value is: BNST -> USWEOLN

I can't see the error. Can anyone help me diagnose this error, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works if you put the string literal in place of Fields!ILS_LS_USER_10.Value.

The issue is that it isn't getting the value of the field as a string by default. Use the ToString() method after .Value and it should work, or at least it did on my machine.

```
=Trim(Left(Fields!ILS_LS_USER_10.Value.ToString(),InStr(Fields!ILS_LS_USER_10.Value.ToString(),"->")-2))
```

Answer (score -1):

I found that the Group expressions, for some reason, do not seem to like the subtraction in the InStr. Leave out the subtraction and it works.
In fact, take the same formula, and place it into a placeholder in the Group and it seems to work just fine. Replaced with Split in the Group expression and it works.
This was on SQL Server 2016, using Report Builder.